Pixel graphics specialist program
I am looking for a free professional software that:

Performs complex pixel computations.
Supports building shapes through a path tool, with comfortable curve control points.
Provides a very easy GUI to perform all that.
Supports importing or dragging existing images into (whether from the clipboard, or from the Open File dialog), resulting into a new layer.
Uses a layer system for different pixel canvas.
Supports filters and effects (shadow, color transforms, brightness adjustment)
Supports anti-aliasing
Supports inserting text and rasterizing it into pixels.

How more how better.
For example, in my case there is GIMP, but it is really different ("not easy").
